# Manage Customers returns a fatal error

Tags: customer, customer-account

Upgraded to 1.9.0.1

When we now attempt to manage customers we can search a customer record but when we choose any record to look at it or edit it we get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword() in /home1/{oursite}/public_html/[oursite].com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php on line 205

I cannot tell what it's actually asking me to do here. Help?!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php` I can confirm that there is no such function **getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword()**.

Which is obviously not present in `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data.php` file too.

So, I would say when you upgraded you didn't replace magento fresh files for this version, at least `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data.php` file is not correctly updated.

I would try to replace these both files and see if that helps.

I doubt since it is not successfully upgraded, there are other issues too.